# IllegalArgumentException: A required type converter is missing in the database configuration

Tags: android

I have a crash when compiling (runtime) my application because according to the error displayed, the converter is missing in the configuration of my database. how could I solve this? I need help please.

The source code below:

WordInfoDao.kt

```
 @Dao

    interface WordInfoDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWordInfos(infos: List<WordInfoEntity>)
    @Query("DELETE FROM wordinfoentity WHERE word IN(:words)")
    suspend fun deleteWordInfos(words: List<String>)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM wordinfoentity WHERE word LIKE '%' || :word || '%'")
    suspend fun getWordInfos(word: String): List<WordInfoEntity> 
}
```

WordInfoDatabase.kt

```
@Database(
    entities = [WordInfoEntity::class],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class WordInfoDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val dao: WordInfoDao
}
```

Converters.kt

```
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class Converters(
    private val jsonParser: com.example.dictionary_app.util.JsonParser
) {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromMeaningsJson(json: String): List<Meaning>{
        return jsonParser.fromJson<ArrayList<Meaning>>(
            json,
            object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Meaning>>(){}.type
        )?: emptyList()
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toMeaningsJson(meanings: List<Meaning>): String{
        return jsonParser.toJson(
            meanings,
            object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Meaning>>(){}.type
        ) ?: "[]"
    }
}
```

WordInfoEntity.kt

```
@Entity
data class WordInfoEntity(
    val word: String,
    val phonetic: String,
    val origin: String,
    val meanings: List<Meaning>,
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int? = null
){
    fun toWordInfo(): WordInfo {
        return WordInfo(
            meanings = meanings,
            word = word,
            origin = origin,
            phonetic = phonetic
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `@ProvidedTypeConverter`, `Room` will not create it automatically. So when you create your database, you must add the converter manually like below

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideWordInfoDatabase(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context, serializer: Serializer
): WordInfoDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, WordInfoDatabase::class.java, "WordInfoDatabase")
    .addTypeConverter(WordInfoConverters(serializer))
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
```

UPDATED:

```
@Entity
data class WordInfoEntity(
    val word: String,
    val phonetic: String,
    val origin: String,
    val meanings: List<Meaning>,
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int? = null
)

data class Meaning(
    val meaning: String,
    val etc: String,
)

@ProvidedTypeConverter
class WordInfoConverters(
    private val jsonParser: Serializer
) {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromMeaningsJson(json: String): List<Meaning>{
        return jsonParser.deserialize<ArrayList<Meaning>>(
            json,
            object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Meaning>>(){}.type
        )
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toMeaningsJson(meanings: List<Meaning>): String{
        return jsonParser.serialize(
            meanings,
        )
    }
}

@Dao
interface WordInfoDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWordInfos(infos: List<WordInfoEntity>)
    @Query("DELETE FROM wordinfoentity WHERE word IN(:words)")
    suspend fun deleteWordInfos(words: List<String>)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM wordinfoentity WHERE word LIKE '%' || :word || '%'")
    suspend fun getWordInfos(word: String): List<WordInfoEntity>
}

@Database(
    entities = [WordInfoEntity::class],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(WordInfoConverters::class)
abstract class WordInfoDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val dao: WordInfoDao
}
```

Comment: It's not getting implemented though i tried

Comment: Post it log error please

Comment: And show the updated code please

Comment: actually what shall i pass in addTypeConverter ??

Comment: can you please elaborate the code whatever you said?

Comment: I've already shown you the code to create a room database with @ProvidedTypeConverter in my answer

Comment: If you got crash, please show the crash log

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A required type converter (class com.example.dictionary_app.local.Converters) for com.example.dictionary_app.local.WordInfoDao is missing in the database configuration.


this is the error i'm getting in the logcat

Comment: You need to provide a converter for List<Meaning>

Comment: Or mark it as @Embeded

Comment: if you don't mind just please write the code of what you're saying for the converter... just please write the correct code...

Comment: import androidx.datastore.core.Serializer
is it the import statement?

Comment: No, it correspond to your Parser, since I did not know the class